# Wordpress Best way to display high resolution images in post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I currently have on my wordpress blog a 'Featured Image' and now just moving onto the single.php pages. How would I go about displaying a high resolution image on this page which isn't the featured image? and then modifying it in CSS e.g Floats / Width etc.

Is there any best practices I should be following?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Thumbnail Sizes

The default image sizes of WordPress are "thumbnail" (and its "thumb" alias), "medium", "large" and "full" (the image you uploaded). These image sizes can be configured in the WordPress Administration Media panel under Settings > Media. If your theme enables Post Thumbnails then "post-thumbnail" is also available and this is the default when using Post Thumbnails. This is how you use these default sizes with the_post_thumbnail():

// without parameter -> Post Thumbnail (as set by theme using set_post_thumbnail_size())
the_post_thumbnail();

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions
```